# What are bitcoin miners actually solving?

Tags: mining-theory, proof-of-work

I've read all other answer, but nobody really gives an answer. Whom for are they solving, and what entity outside BTC community has benefits from all the electric energy wasted in the process of doing math?

Comment: The mining process is designed to generate a relatively constant number of blocks per time unit, independent of the total hashing power being used. Hashing and difficulty adjustment are just a mechanism to achieve this goal, they don't serve any other purpose. Of course, nobody outside of the bitcoin community profits from this process.

Comment: The "problem" they are solving isn't actually a problem anyone has.  It's like digging holes in the ground and then filling them up again.  The point is to prove that they did work.  The work being performed is not important, nor needed/used by anyone.